# Why am I getting an access violation runtime error?

Tags: c++

The problem occurs when I call the `insert(T)` member function of `BTree` from `main()`, which calls the `BTree(T)` constructor. The constructor uses the `BTree` member `BNode` pointer (root) and should set the value of the the `BNode` object to the parameter that is passed to the constructor using `root->value = key` (key is the constructor parameter of type T). I don't understand why `root->value = key;` is causing a memory access violation.

```
template <typename T>
class BNode
{
  public:
      BNode(T key, BNode<T> *lptr, BNode<T> *rptr);
      T value;
      BNode<T> *left, *right;
};

template <typename T>
class BTree
{
  public:
      BTree();
      BTree(T& key, BTree<T>* LT, BTree<T>* RT);
      BTree(T key);
      ~BTree();
      void remove(BNode<T> *rt);
      void insert(T key);

  private:
      BNode<T> *root;

};


template<typename T>
BNode<T>::BNode(T val, BNode<T> *lptr, BNode<T> *rptr)
{
    value = val;
    left = lptr;
    right = rptr;
}


template<typename T>
BTree<T>::BTree()
{
    root = NULL;
}

template<typename T>
BTree<T>::BTree(T& key, BTree<T> *LT, BTree<T> *RT)
{
    root->value = key;
    root->left = LT->root;
    root->right = RT->root;
}

template <typename T>
BTree<T>::BTree(T key) 
{
    root->value = key;
}

template<typename T>
BTree<T>::~BTree()
{
    remove(root);
}

template<typename T>
void BTree<T>::remove(BNode<T> *rt)
{
    if (rt != NULL)
    {
        remove(rt->left);
        remove(rt->right);
        delete rt;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void BTree<T>::insert(T key) //takes postfix expression onto tree
{
        BTree<T> tree(key);

}

int main()
{
    BTree<int> tree;
    tree.insert(5);
}
```

Comment: Debugging is a very useful tool for finding answers to these kind of questions. Step through the code and watch what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your issues with this code is that when you construct

```
BTree<T> tree(key);
```

in `void BTree<T>::insert(T key)` you call

```
template <typename T>
BTree<T>::BTree(T key) 
{
    root->value = key;
}
```

Since `root` was never initialized you are dereferencing a garbage pointer which is undefined behavior.

I would also like to point out that your `insert` function is doing nothing but creating a node that is going to be destroyed.  You actually need to add the node into the list.  You can see how a binary tree would be implemented at [Binary Search Tree C++ Implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/61671/binary-search-tree-c-implementation)

Answer (score 3):

Your `root` pointer is not initialized and you are trying to dereference it when doing the following in your constructor:

```
root->value = key;
root->left = LT->root;
root->right = RT->root;
```

Dereferencing this pointer which is not initialize is causing the segmentation fault.